# Using matplotlib: ImportError: No module named animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, enthought

I've tried using the EPD installation on Mac OS X, the apt-get install process on Ubuntu, and the EPD installation on Ubuntu.

In the python interactive interpretor:

```
>>> import matplotlib.animation as animation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named animation
```

That import is used in this matplotlib example code:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/animation/double_pendulum_animated.html

Comment: `matplotlib.__version__` ? It's there for me on 1.1.0.  Do you have a file `animation.py` in the same folder as your matplotlib `__init__.py` file?   (`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py` for me)

Comment: Version is 1.0.1 and I can't find animation.py using 'sudo find / -name animation.py' Thanks a lot for the fast response! I'll see if using 1.1.0 fixes the issue.

Comment: Yes, `animation` module is new in 1.1.0. See the [release notes](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/whats_new.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, you should be able to update to matplotlib 1.1.0 or 1.2.0 using `enpkg matplotlib [version]`.

https://support.enthought.com/entries/22415022-Using-enpkg-to-update-EPD-packages